# Olivere v5 to Olivere v6: AutoGeneratePhraseQueries equivalant

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm updating my es instance from v5 to v6, however i'm having some issues. This is how we're handling wildcards on elasticsearch v5 (olivere v5)

```
predicate.AutoGeneratePhraseQueries(!param.Wildcard)
```

However, in Elasticsearch v6 (olivere v6) this was removed. How can i keep this function? I can't seem to find the equivalent in the docs. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more code in the question and what is `param.Wildcard` ? I'm assuming it's a boolean value?

Comment: I would suggest asking the author on GitHub by opening an issue there. He is very much active in resolving devs problems related to the usage of the ES Go client API.